# Necessary to lubricate old electric motor?

Tags: motor, dc-motor

I'm in the process of digitizing some old audio reels. The reel-to-reel player is very old and it tends to slow down after it's been on for a while. I was thinking that maybe the motor needed to be lubed up, but I'm not sure if that's correct. Any idea if this sort of motor should be oiled/lubed and the proper way to go about it?

[image]
[image]

Comment: I always wanted to see the inside of Bang and Olufsen audio equipment. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

YES. In the farm we do it all the time. A bit of grease is better than oil. You can remove the two screws and separate the carriers. In the motors pictured, there should be a bushing, so no ball bearings will be falling out (hopefully)!. Other than the bearings, not much else to fail on these shy of burning up the coils. When you put it back together, lightly tighten the screws, rotate by hand. When snug, power up very briefly. Tighten up, maybe a bit of thread-lock (easy does it) and you should be good for another 20 years!. If you remove the rotor, clean the dust out of the gap too!

Comment: Should there be lubricant placed between the coils and the ... inner magnet thingy? :)

Comment: No, only on the bearings (technically bushings).  There should not be lubricant in the gap as there should be no contact between the rotor and stator at all - if rust of the laminations has filled the gap, that could be a problem.

Comment: Thanks. So, it's not working any more. :) The rotor is very stiff once everything is put back together. Hard to even move by hand. And I checked over and over and over and can't see how I could have screwed something up! But oh well, that's enough for now. I have a feeling the motor was on its last leg anyway since it barely had enough force to move the reels at all.

Comment: @JoshM. - If it's hard to turn after reassembly, you've slightly misaligned the bushings. Loosen and re-tighten the screws that clamp the end-caps together.

Answer (score 2):

If there were a problem with lubrication, we would expect that it would be slower when cold, and up to speed after warming up (and making the lubricant more fluid). Because your symptoms are the opposite, it may not be a simple matter of lubrication.  There may be some electrical problem that only appears after components warm up.

Comment: Also, examine the drive system between the motor and the capstan flywheel. If it's an old rubber belt, it may be slipping. Rubber loses tension as it warms up.

Comment: What you describe would be true if there were too much of a heavy grease like lubricant, but not if there were no longer any effective lubricant.  Dave's point about belts on the other hand is spot on.